is it possible to see execution order of all the testcases in a test suite in real time?
In my TestRigor test suite I have parallel test execution turned off.   I want to know if it's possible to know in which order testcases were executed in the real time.
If  I have ten testcases in a suite (testcase 1, testcase 2, ..., testcase 10), what order are they executed?
I have a testcase that keeps randomly failing when trying to select a value from a dropdown. Scenario is:
enter ID -> click Next button -> new page loads -> select a value from a dropdown.
Each step in the scenario is performed by  a reusable rule.
There are around 20 other testcases in the suite that follow the same scenario and  use the same rules. All of them have been passing  for 2+ weeks without single failure. It's just this one testcase that randomly fails.
We are suspecting some kind of database  problem (locking issue on the table), but to  confirm that we need to know order of execution in the real time

If you want to achieve a sequential order, it's not possible. The tests will run in the order they are executed by the user.
If you still would like to control few of them as per your needs you can do it using labels.
